# Blank Screen After login in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

Hello I use Ubuntu LTS 14.04 and It was working fine yesterday when I login  today I get a Blank Screen with only movable mouse pointer .

I tried ctl+ alt +F1 and login in and then rm .Xauthority as most topics said but I still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling lightdm

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

Comment: still the same issue .. now it gets logged out as soon as I login